# How to join tables in SQL Server to get the expected result

Tags: sql-server

Table USERS:

```
UID  |  NAME
------------
100  |  RAVI
101  |  Raju
102  |  Manju
103  |  Arun
```

Table SESSION:

```
SID |    DATE   | TIME  | STrain_ID 
----------------------------------
1   | 1/1/2015  | 11:30 | 1
2   | 12/1/2015 | 12:30 | 2
3   | 25/1/2015 | 01:30 | 3
4   | 25/1/2015 | 02:30 | 4
```

Table TRAINERS:

```
Train_ID | Primary   | secondarry   | other     | primID | secID | otherID
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1        | RAVI      |              | Manju     | 100    |      |  102
2        |           | RAVI         |           |        | 100  |
3        |           |              | RAVI      |        |      |  100
4        |           | Manju        | Ravi      |        | 102  |  100
```

Expected result

```
SID | DATE      | TIME  | Train_ID | NAME | ROLE
-------------------------------------------------
1   | 1/1/2015  | 11:30 | 1        | RAVI |primary
1   | 1/1/2015  | 11:30 | 1        | Manju|other
2   | 12/1/2015 | 12:30 | 2        | RAVI |secondary
3   | 25/1/2015 | 01:30 | 3        | RAVI |other
4   | 25/1/2015 | 02:30 | 4        | Manju|secondary
```

Comment: Where is the question? What is the "expected result"? What have you tried so far? What does "RAVI 101" mean, is this tow bits of information?

Comment: i have added expected result

Comment: Thx, much better :-)   But what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please add your code to the question.

Comment: You're storing both IDs and names into trainers table? Sounds like a problem in the design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below query,

```
select s.*,u.Name,t.src from [SESSION] s  join  
(select Train_ID,primID as usr,'primary' src from TRAINERS where primID is not null
union all
select Train_ID,secID, 'secondary' src from TRAINERS where secID is not null
union all
select Train_ID,otherID, 'others' src from TRAINERS where otherID is not null) t
 on s.[sid]=t.train_id join  USERS u on t.usr=u.[UID]
```

Comment: Thank you for ur valuable time ANK, this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Check below code. I saw the pattern of expected result, there will be one more row 4-Train_ID, Ravi as "Others" role. As @JamesZ already mentioned about your design, you will have to work on that also.

```
SELECT S.SID, S.DATE, S.TIME, S.STrain_ID AS Train_ID ,U.NAME, CASE WHEN T.[Primary] = U.NAME THEN 'Primary'
                                                        WHEN T.[Secondary]  = U.NAME THEN 'Secondary'
                                                        WHEN T.[Others]  = U.NAME THEN 'Others'  END AS [ROLE]
FROM #SESSION S
INNER JOIN #TRAINERS T ON S.STrain_ID = T.Train_ID
LEFT JOIN #USERS U ON (U.Name = T.[Primary])OR (U.Name = T.[Secondary]) OR (U.Name = T.Others)
```

Mark it answered if it helps you.

Comment: Did it help your problem?